# How to find out which columns in random Excel sheets are dates or currency using Interop and C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an application that reads excel files and extracts all the data. The xlsx or xls files are not standard and vary in column size, column data type, and row size. My application currently is able to read all files of this nature but when I use Value2 all the dates are coming back as OLE Automation type (32442,45322..). After researching its clear that Value2 is returning the underlying data as days from Dec 30, 1899 in the double data type.

Im currently calling Value2 only once and moving everything into an object array:

```
object[,] data = xlRange.Value2;
```

Then depending on the rows size, column size, and if there is header Im reading everything into a new temp table that gets bulk copied into the file's matching table in the db.

Before the file is read, I perform a setup process like how many rows to skip at the top, the column names, if it has header, the header column names...

Now is there a way for me to automatically detect which columns are dates or currency without having to explicitly let the application know which columns to handle differently? I was able to solve this problem by labeling the columns that were dates as DATES and using the FromOADate function to load it as a date string but not really happy with this solution.

```
                                            for (int r = startRow; r <= rowCount - rowsAfter; r++)   //populates the raw table with all file rows
                                            {
                                                //if (i % 100 == 0)
                                                //MessageBox.Show("Message" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                                                //Application.DoEvents();
                                                object[] rowData = new object[colCount];
                                                for (int c = 1; c <= colCount; c++)
                                                {
                                                    bool isDateColumn = false;
                                                    string tempGridFieldName = fieldListcount_excel2[c - 1];  //checks the fieldListNames and looks for keywork Date
                                                    if (tempGridFieldName.Contains("DATE"))
                                                        isDateColumn = true; //suppose to be true

                                                    int maxFieldSize = Int32.Parse(fieldListlength_excel2[c - 1]); //changed this to version 2
                                                    if (data[r, c] != null)
                                                    {
                                                        int cellSize = data[r, c].ToString().Length;  //gets max cell size from grid
                                                        if (cellSize <= maxFieldSize)
                                                            if (isDateColumn) //column is a date field so we take the Excel serial date and convert it to Datetime
                                                            {
                                                                object o = data[r, c];
                                                                double d = Convert.ToDouble(o);
                                                                DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
                                                                rowData[c - 1] = dt.ToShortDateString();
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                rowData[c - 1] = data[r, c];
                                                            }
                                                        else
                                                        {

                                                            MessageBox.Show($"Cell [{r},{c}] content size larger than field size");
                                                            cellOversizeFlag = true;
                                                            eof = false;
                                                            break;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        rowData[c - 1] = data[r, c];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                rawExcelFileDT.Rows.Add(rowData);

                                            }
```

I also tried to check the columns by using the getType function but the column names were always strings and the dates came back as doubles. The problem is that I cannot assume that all the doubles will be dates so how can I approach this problem?

Comment: According to Microsoft website: "The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types." So, why don't you use `Value` instead of `Value2`? The `Value` property returns Date and Time

Comment: I tried Value but it didnt make a difference. The dates came back as 44323, 44354... so I just stuck with Value2.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually I tried it again and it did work this time. I must have not build or looked at the wrong data. Also, when I cycled through the columns to get the data type now all the dates come back as dateTimes. Is there another way to do this if I needed to use Value2?

Comment: `Value2` returns date/time as double by design! So, you should add some intelligence into your code. for example,  if you know the date range you may use `DateTime.FromOADate()` to convert the double into date and if it is within the expected range, you may conclude the content is date. of course, you should double check this by checking other values in the column. but it would not be perfect!